# Hover problems on iPhone/iPad

Tags: iphone, css, hover

I've just changed the layout of my site and I'm having a few issues - I've got a stylesheet for iPhone that i'm selecting with the following:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" media="only screen and (max-device-width: 480px)" href="scripts/page-phone.css" />
```

I'm having an issue with accessing some links on iPhone - I think it's due to some rogue CSS, but I'm having a bit of a problem tracking it down - In the normal CSS I have the following code:

```
.griditem {
    position: relative;
    display:inline-block;
    margin-right: 17px;
    margin-bottom: 17px;
    background-color: #777;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    box-shadow: 0 1px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    -webkit-border-radius: 2px;
    -moz-border-radius: 2px;
    border-radius: 2px;
    width: 480px;
    height: 271px;
    text-align: left;
}


.titles {
    padding: 0px;
    bottom: 0px;
    position: absolute;
    left: -1px;
    right: -1px;
    top: -1px;
    -moz-border-radius: 1px 1px 0 0;
    border-radius: 1px 1px 0 0;
    text-align: center;
    display: none;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    -moz-border-radius: 1px 1px 0 0;
    border-radius: 1px 1px 0 0;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

.griditem:hover .titles {
    display:  block;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.titles a:link {
    text-decoration: none;
}​
```

and in my 'Phone' CSS -

```
.griditem {
    position: relative;
    display:inline-block;
    margin-right: 17px;
    margin-bottom: 17px;
    background-color: #777;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    box-shadow: 0 1px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    -webkit-border-radius: 2px;
    -moz-border-radius: 2px;
    border-radius: 2px;
    width: 480px;
    height: 271px;
    text-align: left;
}


.titles {
    padding: 5px;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0px;
    left: -1px;
    right: -1px;
    background: transparent url(../images/layout/white80.png) top left;
    -moz-border-radius: 1px 1px 0 0;
    border-radius: 1px 1px 0 0;
    text-align: left;
}

.titles a:link {
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

The HTML is as follows:

```
<a class="griditem" href="video.php" style="background-image:url(image.jpg); background-size:100% 100%;">
    <img src="spacer.png" width="100%" href="video.php" alt="Title" />
    <div class="titles">
        <div class="gridholder">
            <h5>Title</h5>
            <h6>Subtitle<BR>+</h6>
        </div>
    </div>
</a>
```

For some reason though on the phone the links don't work(!) - I've been looking at this problem that I can't see the obvious - Any ideas from looking at the code?

Comment: .tiles doesn't have a display:block; on it.

Comment: use this in top of css and remove media attribute from the link tag:
`@media screen and (max-device-width: 480px)`

Comment: doesn't works means? do not show up? or they have some styles missing?

Comment: They 'griditem's show up - but when clicked on nothing happens, the rollover state briefly appears but then nothing happens

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I've worked around this by changing the layout - instead of the '.titles' covering the table on rollover, the iphone version is always present as a footer on the '.griditem' - Not a fix per se, more a workaround but it works and still looks good so for now I'll take it!

Here is the new CSS for '.titles' in the iPhone CSS:

```
.titles {
    padding: 5px;
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    bottom: 0px;
    top: 75%;
    left: -1px;
    right: -1px;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    -moz-border-radius: 1px 1px 0 0;
    border-radius: 1px 1px 0 0;
    text-align: left;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Is there any specific reason for using:
    `<img src="spacer.png" width="100%" href="video.php" alt="Title" />`
Try getting rid of this line, as you already are haveing a HREF specified in `<a>` tag. 
Add style `display:block` for the `<a>` element.

Thanks,
Pav

Comment: I've removed the second HREF but the links still dont seem to work on iPhone - they require a double tap which sometimes zooms, sometimes loads the page.

The really confusing thing is that I don't have a hover state specified in my iPhone CSS so I'm not even sure why it is activating - I'm testing on an iPhone 5, not sure if that makes a difference to the media selector.

Comment: HAve you tried specifying the href url as an absolutes path like http://mydomain/video.php instead of the relative link.